# how to rip li from ul div table

Tags: jquery

I have a code similar to this:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The problem is that I cannot change the html code. I have to do it with jQuery.

I need to remove the `<li>` content in order to make the li the same width as the main div. Any other solution that I've come up doesn't work.

Comment: Look into `replaceWith()`: http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

Comment: if you have to make `li` of the same width as of `div` then why you want to remove it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this to empty them:

`$('li').html('');`

Or this to remove them all together:

`$('li').remove();`

Answer (score 1):

You can change the width of element directly if you prefer, why do you need to remove it http://jsfiddle.net/Fx8DD/1/

```
// js
$("#remove").click(function() {
  $('li').remove();
});

$("#change").click(function() {
  $('li').width('200px');
});
// html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="mod">Some li</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<button id="remove" type="button">Remove</button>
<button id="change" type="button">Chnage width/button>

// css 
.mod { background: blue; cursor: default; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you are looking for: { even i really don't understand what you want to do }

http://jsfiddle.net/vwxgd/

```
var $ul = $('ul');
$ul.replaceWith($.trim($ul.text()));
```

Comment: Whitespace doesn't render in html (other than a single space), so this isn't likely to chance the width much, if at all.

Comment: @LukeCousins $.trim() here is used for browser compatibility, especially older version of IE and/or jquery which can add some specific characters at end of a string making invalid html. But still, i don't understand what OP wants to do here.